# How to know which terminal emulator I'm using?

Tags: terminal

I heard there are plenty of terminal emulator: xterm, aterm, terminator, etc.

Since I'd like to play with the color escape code `\033[`, and wiki said some of its feature is not wildly support, so I need to know which terminal I'm running on.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and pretty sure that I'm running on GNU Screen in GUI mode, but couldn't figure out which terminal I'm on when I hit Ctrl+Alt+F3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this command in your terminal.

```
echo $TERM
```

The output will be what kind of terminal emulator you are using.

Comment: This answer seems to contradict https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93376/which-terminal-type-am-i-using.

Comment: When I wrote this in 2013, I either did not understand the $TERM variable or I was not paying full attention to the question. Echoing $TERM will tell you the capabilities of your terminal, not which terminal emulator you are running. For example, when I run this command in Terminator I get `xterm-256-color`, meaning it emulates xterm which was one of or the first terminal emulator for X and it can display 256 different colors.